# VB.NET HttpWebRequest - Posting To Forum

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

I was wondering if you could help me with this "HttpWebRequest".

I learned how to login to a forum which was pretty easy to do. Here is the login string that I found in LiveHttpHeaders:

**"http://rocbattle.com/check_login.php?pg=http://rocbattle.com/index.php"**

And here is the post string for logging in through this request:

**"username=acebeats1&password=Jordan123&remember=remember&login=: undefined"**

But I don't know what to do after I login. I'm trying to create a POST to this section of the forum (BUY/SELL/TRADE):
**http://rocbattle.com/viewforumrb.php?f=16&sid=3767e7ef319b85e69321fe2c3c92b499**

So I guess my question would be; how do I carry the login cookie & submit a new post to the "BUY/SELL/TRADE" section?

HERE IS THE CODE THAT I'M USING SO FAR:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text


 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim postData As String = "username=" & TextBox1.Text & "&password=" & TextBox2.Text & "&remember=remember&login=: undefined"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://rocbattle.com/check_login.php?pg=http://rocbattle.com/index.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "http://rocbattle.com/check_login.php?pg=http://rocbattle.com/index.php"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        'Webbrowser show results:
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the sent the request for posting in the section you want !

Comment: Note: You don't need to use 2 **CookieContainer**s. Just path the same CookieContainer to your requests and it should handle cookies without using .Add method

Comment: Thank you for your reply Youssef. But can you give me an example of how I would then process the next URL string for POSTING after the LOGIN URL has been processed? I would appreciate a quick example with the code given above if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and what is the difference between Fiddler vs using LiveHTTPheaders (Mozilla Firefox extension)??? Is the "sent" information for posting not included in the LiveHTTPHeaders Firefox extension? I thought that it was already in LiveHTTPheaders or that this extension could already find that URL string.

Comment: Also, this is the next URL that I'm trying to process along with it's POST string:

http://rocbattle.com/postingrb.php?mode=post&f=16

Comment: And here is what the POST string looks like:

Comment: subject=HERE+IS+MY+MESSAGE+SUBJECT%3F%3F%3F&addbbcode20=100&helpbox=Tip%3A+Styles+can+be+applied+quickly+to+selected+text.&message=HERE+IS+MY+MSG!!!...&attach_sig=on&notify=on&lastclick=1504558607&post=Submit&creation_time=1504558607&form_token=70f9dcf3e8207cebe5e169e4fb2479ba97fcee73: undefined

Comment: So using the code I've mentioned above, how would I execute the POST after my successful LOGIN? I would like an example if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't try LiveHTTPHeaders, but I prefer Fiddler because you can see both requests, from browsers and from your applications.
You shouldn't send the POST string you captured as it is, because the form_token isn't constant. You should first capture form_token.

Comment: Where does the "form_token" exist so that I can capture & use it? Would it most-likely be within the html of the page or do I have to somehow capture it in the "Response"???

Comment: I didn't check, but usually you will find it in the GET response when you press Add New Thread

Comment: Okay, so I see that the POST STRING requires the following 3:

lastclick=
creation_time=
form_token=

and I can see that they all exist on the main thread posting page:
http://rocbattle.com/postingrb.php?mode=post&f=16

How do I extract these values with the HttpWebRequest & POST it to this section of the forum?

Comment: Okay, so I see that the POST STRING requires the following 3:

Comment: lastclick=     creation_time=      form_token=

Comment: and I can see that they all exist & are generated on the main thread posting page:

Comment: http://rocbattle.com/postingrb.php?mode=post&f=16

Comment: How do I extract these values with the HttpWebRequest & POST it to this section of the forum?

Comment: Send **GET** request to the that URL, Read the response. You can use regex like this and capture the group 1. `name="form_token" value="(.+?)"`

Comment: I figured out how to right my own Regex to parse those values, but now how do I POST them? Also, I noticed that you ran some tests on Rocbattle as I can see that you posted there. Were you able to figure it out?